# How can i merge two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this query through i am getting reult

```
$query_message1 = "select a.new,a.mes_id,a.frm_id,a.mem_id,a.subject,a.body,a.date,a.read from messages_system as a where a.frm_id='$memId' and a.type='message' order by date desc limit $lowerlimit,$limit";
             $exeMessage=execute_query($query_message1,true,"select");
$message =$exeMessage;
print_r($message);

foreach($exeMessage as $kk=>$mem){

             $query_message2 = "select b.profilenam,b.photo_thumb,b.gender,b.profile_type from members as b where b.mem_id='".$mem['mem_id']."'";
            $exeMessage1 = execute_query($query_message2,true,"select");
           //print_r($exeMessage);
            if (empty($exeMessage1)) {
            echo "0";
            $img = "images/my-profile-img3-big.gif";
              // print_r($message['mes_id']);
                    $exeMessage1['profilenam']='Annonymous';
                    $exeMessage1['photo_thumb']=$img;
                    $exeMessage1['gender']='m';
                    $exeMessage1['profile_type']='';
                    $message[$kk] = $exeMessage1;

            }

            }
```

well print_r($message); line gives me

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [new] => new
            [mes_id] => 1030
            [frm_id] => 329
            [mem_id] => 39
            [subject] =>  aaaa
            [body] => aaaa
            [date] => 1310285289
            [read] => read
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [new] => viewed
            [mes_id] => 1029
            [frm_id] => 329
            [mem_id] => 397
            [subject] =>  aaaa
            [body] => aaaa
            [date] => 1310285188
            [read] => read
        )
 )
```

and line `$message[$kk] = array_merge($exeMessage1,$message[$kk]);`
gives me result of condition   `if (empty($exeMessage1)) {`

now i want to merge these two arrays so that the final result will be like this

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [new] => new
            [mes_id] => 1030
            [frm_id] => 329
            [mem_id] => 39
            [subject] =>  aaaa
            [body] => aaaa
            [date] => 1310285289
            [read] => read
            [profilenam] => Annonymous
            [photo_thumb] => images/my-profile-img3-big.gif
            [gender] => m
            [profile_type] => 



        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [new] => viewed
            [mes_id] => 1029
            [frm_id] => 329
            [mem_id] => 397
            [subject] =>  aaaa
            [body] => aaaa
            [date] => 1310285188
            [read] => read
            [profilenam] => Purple Test
            [photo_thumb] => photos/19db7b14c0ebdb98838fdafb46b3a1ebth.jpeg
            [gender] => n
            [profile_type] => C
        )
)
```

PLease Help
Thanks

here is the solution

```
$query_message1 = "select a.new,a.mes_id,a.frm_id,a.mem_id,a.subject,a.body,a.date,a.read from messages_system as a where a.frm_id='$memId' and a.type='message' order by date desc limit $lowerlimit,$limit";
            $exeMessage = execute_query($query_message1, true, "select");
            $totalResult = "select a.new,a.mes_id,a.frm_id,a.mem_id,a.subject,a.body,a.date,a.read from messages_system as a where a.frm_id='$memId' and a.type='message' order by date desc";
            $exetotalResult = execute_query($totalResult, true, "select");

            foreach ($exeMessage as $kk => $mem) {

                $query_message2 = "select b.profilenam,b.photo_thumb,b.gender,b.profile_type from members as b where b.mem_id='" . $mem['mem_id'] . "'";
                $exeMessage1 = execute_query($query_message2, true, "select");

                if (empty($exeMessage1)) {
                    $img = "images/my-profile-img3-big.gif";
                    $exeMessage1[$kk]['profilenam'] = 'Annonymous';
                    $exeMessage1[$kk]['photo_thumb'] = $img;
                    $exeMessage1[$kk]['gender'] = 'm';
                    $exeMessage1[$kk]['profile_type'] = '';
                }
                $message[$kk] = array_merge((array) $mem, (array) $exeMessage1[0]);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

Comment: Off-topic, you should be using prepared statements rather than interpolating values directly into statements. Prepared statements are safer and more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use the `array_merge()` function.

Comment: Well not recursively, so you meant probably `array_merge_recursive()`.